# How can i make angular route with query parameters that must be required?

Tags: angular

If i want to do angular route with required parametes then i would write this in `app-routing.module.ts`

```
 { path: 'users/:id', component: UserDetailsComponent },
```

i need to have now angular route but with query parameters.

I know that i can build this from the typescript file for example something like

```
 this.router.navigate(['.'], {
      relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
      queryParams: {departmentId:1},
      queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
    });
```

but the problem is that when the user for example can delete the query parameter `departmentId=1` from my route

`localhost:4200/users?departmentId=1` and the page will still load.
I want in that case t show the 404 page, for which i have the wild card in the app routing module.

How can i do this ?

Comment: If it's a mandatory part of the route maybe it *shouldn't* be a query parameter? Or why not navigate to the 404 page if the users route is loaded but there's no query parameter in the activated route?

Answer (score 1):

You can check in the `url` if the query parameter `departmentId` exists, and if not you can redirect the user to some other page (404 page if you have one).

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

...

 constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
 ) { }

 ngOnInit(): void {
    let departmentId = this.route.snapshot.params.departmentId;
    if(!departmentId) this.router.navigate(['otherPage'])
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to the ActivatedRouteSnapshot inside the constructor of your component, it will give you all the required items, queryParams, url at the beginning at that very moment you can apply the routing logic.

Read more on https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot